# Delete all occurrences of an element in a linkedlist

Tags: java, linked-list, implementation

On my quest to understand data structures , i started implementing them in java.The time complexity for  `deleteAll` would be `O(n + n^2)`.How can i improve the `deleteAll` method ?

```
/*
 * Singly linked list
 */
package linkedlisttest;

class Node {

    int data;
    Node next;

    public Node(int data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

}

class LinkedList {

    Node head;
    int size;

    /**
     *
     * @param data element to add to list 
     * Time Complexity : O(n)
     */
    public void add(int data) {
        if (head == null) {
            head = new Node(data);
            size += 1;
            return;
        }

        Node current = head;
        while (current.next != null) {
            current = current.next;
        }
        current.next = new Node(data);
        size += 1;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return size of list 
     * Time Complexity: O(1) 
     * This is because we use a class
     * variable size to keep track of size of linked list
     */
    public int getSize() {
        return size;
    }
    /**
     * 
     * @param data element to insert 
     * @param index position at which to insert the element (zero based)
     * Time Complexity : O(n)
     */
    public void add(int data, int index) {

        if (index > getSize()) {
            return; // invalid position
        }

        Node current = head; //iterate through whole list 
        int pos = 0;
        Node newNode = new Node(data);

        if (index == 0) // special case, since its a single reference change!
        {
            newNode.next = head;
            head = newNode; // this node is now the head
            size += 1;
            return;
        }
        while (current.next != null) {
            if (pos == index - 1) {
                break;
            }
            pos++;
            current = current.next;
        }
        // These are 2 reference changes, as compared to adding at index 0
        newNode.next = current.next; // here we are changing a refernce
        current.next = newNode; // changing a reference here as well
        size += 1;

    }
    /**
     * Find the first occurrence of an element  
     * @param data element to find
     * @return index at which element is found , -1 if not exist
     * Time Complexity: O(n)
     */
    public int find(int data) {
        Node current = head;
        int pos = 0;
        int index = -1;
        if(head == null) { //empty list
            return index;
        }
        while(current != null) {
            if (current.data == data) {
                index = pos;
                break;
            }
            pos++;
            current = current.next;
        }
        return index;
    }

    /**
     * Delete the first occurrence of data 
     * @param data element to delete 
     * Time complexity : O(n)
     */
    public void delete(int data) {
        Node current = head;
        if (head == null) { // list is empty
            return;
        }
        if(head.data == data) { // if we want to delete the head , make next node head
            head = head.next;
            size -= 1;
            return;
        }
        while(current.next != null) {
            if (current.next.data == data) {
                current.next = current.next.next;
                size -= 1;
                return;
            }
            current = current.next;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Delete all occurrences of data 
     * @param data element to delete 
     * 
     */
    public void deleteAll(int data) {
        Node current = head;
        if (head == null) { // list is empty
            return;
        }
        //while loop to delete consecutive occurances of data
        while(head.data == data) { // if we want to delete the head , make next node head
            head = head.next;
            size -= 1;
        }
        while(current.next != null) {
            //while loop to delete consecutive occurances of data
            while (current.next.data == data) { 
                current.next = current.next.next;
                size -= 1;
            }
            current = current.next;
        }
    }

    public void reverse() {

    }



    /**
     * Prints the whole linked list 
     * Time Complexity : O(n)
     */
    public void print() {

        if(head == null) { //list is empty
            return;
        }
        Node current = head;
        while (current.next != null) {
            System.out.print(current.data + "->");
            current = current.next;
        }
        System.out.print(current.data + "\n"); 
    }
}

public class LinkedListTest {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LinkedList lt = new LinkedList();
        lt.print();
        lt.add(3);
        lt.add(5);
        lt.add(6);
        lt.print();
        lt.add(4, 1);
        lt.print();
        lt.add(4, 7);// 7 is an invalid index
        lt.add(8, 3);
        lt.add(8, 4);
        lt.print();
        System.out.println("Position : " + lt.find(8));
        lt.delete(5);
        lt.print();
        lt.deleteAll(8);
        lt.print();
        System.out.println("Size : " + lt.getSize());
    }

}
```

Comment: If this code works fine, then this question is off topic on Stack Overflow, but may be good for our sister site [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The time complexity of your implementation is `O(n)`, not `O(n + n^2)` as you believed.
Although a nested loop is a common sign of `O(n^2)` it's not always the case.
The important point is the number of iterations.
In your case,
if you take `k` steps in the nested loop,
that reduces the remaining steps in the outer loop by `k`.
Overall,
you will still be taking `n` steps to reach the end.

But your implementation has some bugs,
and can also be improved:

- Bug: you assign `current = head`, but if `head.data == data` then it will be deleted, and `current` will still point to it
- There is no need for a nested loop. After the special treatment for the head, you can simply follow the nodes and delete the matching items

Like this:

```
public void deleteAll(int data) {
    while (head != null && head.data == data) {
        head = head.next;
        size -= 1;
    }

    if (head == null) {
        return;
    }

    Node current = head;
    while (current.next != null) {
        if (current.next.data == data) {
            current.next = current.next.next;
            size -= 1;
        } else {
            current = current.next;
        }
    }
}
```

By the way, the special treatment of the head can be a bit annoying.
An elegant alternative is to create a dummy that points to `head`:

```
public void deleteAll(int data) {
    Node dummy = new Node();
    dummy.next = head;

    Node current = dummy;
    while (current.next != null) {
        if (current.next.data == data) {
            current.next = current.next.next;
            size -= 1;
        } else {
            current = current.next;
        }
    }

    head = dummy.next;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive explanation and code sample.

Comment: `} else { current = current.next;}` was key here , my early implementation was based on delete and it was always iterating to the next node

Answer (score 0):

Note that everything in Java is reference except those primitive types. So `current` still stays at the original `head`.

It is unnecessary to treat consecutive occurrences as special cases. A simple iterate&judge through the linked list with `O(n)` - linear complexity will do exactly what you want.

Besides, a nested loop doesn't necessarily means it will definitely cost O(n^2). If you move `current` every times, it still walk through the linked list in linear time.

Another personal suggestion: If you need to write something like `node.next.next` when dealing with linked list, it's time to set another reference or to refactor your code.